# pyinstaller and pyomo and also SCIP

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyomo, scip

I would like to package (using pyinstaller) my optimizer program that uses pyomo and scip.  I keep getting pyomo.environ import errors and have been experimenting with hidden imports.  [I saw this](https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/n1Hn8q7Qwmw) and was surprised, but I tried it anyway.  It seems like it should go in a file.  I tried it and as expected doesn't get everything and so the command just keeps getting bigger.  [I am using SCIP](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scip) and so I will have problems there.  I heard that you can add the executable to the optimizer, but I have no idea where conda put that executable.  Can we get a good solution to creating executables (with the extra folders and not just one file) using pyinstaller and featuring pyomo?
It needs an added focus on how to, exactly, add the optimizers (like scip)?